# SiteNavigationElement schema worth using?

Tags: schema.org, rich-snippets

https://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement

Does this Schema.org markup mean your sitelinks from your nav are shown in Google? Or is this completely unrelated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google lists their [Google Search features that make use of Schema.org](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/search-gallery). Currently there doesn’t seem to be a feature for which Schema.org’s `SiteNavigationElement` type is recommended/required. This [doesn’t necessarily mean](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/108334/17633) that Google doesn’t make use of it, but if so, it’s undocumented.

While it’s typically preferable to provide Schema.org structured data even if Google doesn’t consume it, [I think](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/107423/17633) it’s not worth using any of the [`WebPageElement`](https://schema.org/WebPageElement) types (which includes `SiteNavigationElement`), unless in special cases (where you know that you need them).